Error message output accompanied with the run command in tcshell script
#!/bin/tcsh -f

if ( $#argv > 1 ) then
  echo "Wrong!!"
else if ( $#argv == 1 && $1 == cm ) then
   echo bull
else if ( $#argv == 1 && $1 == dm ) then
   echo cow
else
   echo shit
endif

I have implemented the above code to set the environment with certain control parameters. However, when I pass the following run command, it generates the error message along with the run command.
Run command:
source trial a b

Output:
Wrong number of inputssource trial a b

How to solve this issue?
